# Changing --max-stack-size for grunt task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm running into the following error in my GruntJS script:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded"

What's the proper syntax for invoking the node flag `--max-stack-size=` in my grunt command so I can set aside a larger amount of memory for the stack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you are doing some very high-level programming in GruntJS I think you may have a cyclic task registered.

If you name a task the same name as plugin it will run an infinite amount of times:

```
grunt.registerTask('uglify', ['uglify'])
```

This results in the task calling itself.

In order to verify what you're doing, run the grunt with `--verbose` (or --v) command to see what grunt is running.

For instance run `grunt uglify --v` and notice how many times it runs. This can be fixed easily by changing the task name to something else.

If however you're sure of what you're doing run grunt with `--max-stack-size=10000`
or whatever...

Answer (score 2):

Install `grunt-cli` locally with `npm install grunt-cli` then call it locally with:

```
node --max-stack-size=val ./node_modules/.bin/grunt
```

Although likely you're getting that error because of an infinite recursion that should be fixed.

Comment: Any idea about windows?

Answer (score 1):

This should work on linux or mac:

```
node --stack-size=10000 `which grunt`
```

The 10000 can be replaced by whatever size you require.

The default is 984 on my mac and on an ubuntu server I've been working on lately.

Another option is to add this to your `.bashrc`, `.bach_profile` or equivalent:

```
alias grunt='node --stack-size=10000 `which grunt`'
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue happend to me when I dynamicaly called tasks via `grunt.task.run()`.
Seems that grunt's `success` callbacks filled tha NodeJs stack.

I performed manual edit of `c:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt.cmd` (on Windows). Add parameter supported by your version of node, e.g `--stack_size=2000` (for details use `node -help`).